# Git pre-push hook merge conflict

Tags: git, githooks

I'm trying to build my latex file before every push, so I use the `pre-push` script:

```
#!/bin/sh

./compile y    # just does latex,bibtex,latex,latex
if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
    git commit -a --amend --no-edit 
else
    echo "An error has occurred, check the logs in .bits"
fi
```

Every time I push, it succeeds but then I get a merge conflict over the compiled pdf file when I pull. I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're checking in your PDF as part of your repository in the `pre-push` hook.  The `pre-push` hook can't affect what is pushed; it only can accept or reject it.

What's happening is that you're trying to push the version without your PDF file updated (version A), your hook is modifying the commit to update the PDF file (version B), the push succeeds for version A, and then you're trying to pull the remote version (version A) again.  Because your local branch (B) and the remote branch (A) now differ, pulling creates a merge commit.

PDFs are not designed to be line-oriented, and so you get a merge conflict between your old PDF and your new PDF.

There are two things you can do to make this better: don't try to modify things in a pre-push hook (just reject the push if it's not up to date or incomplete) and don't check in build products like a PDF into your repository.  You're much more likely to get a conflict over two binary or non-line-oriented files than over two line-oriented source files.